# Gradle wsdl generating

Tags: java, gradle, wsdl, wsdl2java

I want to generate java files from wsdl. I try to use [wsdl2java](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java) gradle plugin. I define the plugin:

```
subprojects {
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
....
}
```

but I got this error:

```
> Plugin with id 'no.nils.wsdl2java:no.nils:wsdl2java' not found.
```

I checked the syntax (many times it is good). I googled for the plugin, it is used by many people.

Does anybody have an idea what is going wrong?

**Upd:**

I have a main gradle where the plugins defined, and there are three sub project, where I want to use this plugin.

I defined the sub projects in the `settings.gradle`:

```
include 'project1', 'project2', 'project3'
```

I made a folder and the `build.gradle` file for each project.

If I commented out the  `apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'` in the main `build.gradle` and the `wsdl2java` methods in the sub projects the gradle works fine.

Comment: Your code works fine, please provide some more information.

Comment: Hi! Thx for the response, I updated the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add the `buildscript` inside the `subprojects`-closure, thats not supported, see [this Gradle discussion (Buildscript {} in subprojects {} ignored?)](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildscript-in-subprojects-ignored/2401/10).

You do not have to add the buildscript for every project, it is enough to just declare it on the root-build.gradle

```
buildscript{
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'application'
    apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the **wsdl2** java working in my **gradle** build with **jaxws** and **ant** tasks. Here it is

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
       dirs 'lib'
   }
}

configurations { jaxws }
dependencies { jaxws 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-tools:2.2.6' }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.6'
}


task generateSCMOrderImportServiceClient{
    if(!file("./lib/employee-services-client.jar").exists()) {

        def rootDir = file("build/wsdlToJava/employee-services-client");
        def javaDir = file("${rootDir}/java");
        def wsdlJarDir = file("${projectDir}/lib");
        def classesDir = file("${rootDir}/classes");
        def wsdlDir=file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl");
        def wsdlFile = file("${wsdlDir}/employee-services.wsdl")

        doLast{
            classesDir.mkdirs()
            javaDir.mkdirs()
            wsdlJarDir.mkdirs()
            copy {
                from "${wsdlFile}"
                into "${classesDir}"
            }

            ant {
                    taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                            classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                            classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath)
                    wsimport(keep: true,
                            destdir: classesDir,
                            sourcedestdir: javaDir,
                            extension: "true",
                            verbose: "true",
                            quiet: "false",
                            xnocompile: "false",
                            xendorsed: true,
                            wsdlLocation: "EmployeeServices.wsdl",
                            wsdl: "${wsdlFile}") 
                    {
                        binding(dir:"${wsdlDir}", includes:"jaxb-bindings.xml,jaxws-bindings.xml")
                        xjcarg(value: "-XautoNameResolution")
                    }
            }

            ant.jar(
                    destfile: wsdlJarDir.path + "/employee-services-client.jar",
                    basedir: classesDir
            )
        }
     }

}



compileJava.dependsOn generateSCMOrderImportServiceClient
```

Answer (score 2):

I had achieved this task using [this](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java) git repository. The build.gradle file looks something like this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.M6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'no.nils.wsdl2java' version '0.10'
}

group = 'your.application.groupname'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    wsdl2java(
            'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.3.0.1',
            'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1',
            'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1',
            'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:3.2.7',
            'javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1',

            'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1',
            'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.3.2',
            'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2',
            'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    )

    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:3.2.7'
    implementation 'javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

wsdl2java {
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ['-p', 'your.package.name',
             '-autoNameResolution', "$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl/some_wsdl_file.wsdl"]
    ]
    generatedWsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/java")
    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl")
    locale = Locale.ENGLISH
}

wsdl2javaExt {
    cxfVersion = "2.5.1"
}
```

To generate the java code we need to run the gradle task as shown below.

```
$ gradlew wsdl2java
```

Comment: thank you very much for helping me save my 20 days of upcoming effort !

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is looking for generating with Apache CXF. I tried to avoid using any plugin. I did it by creating configuration with dependencies, externalized array of strings with wsdl file names and then just use it like this:

```
ext {
    wsdlDir = file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl")
    outputDir = file("$buildDir/generated-sources")
    sourceWsdls = [
            "$wsdlDir/MyWsdlFile1.wsdl",
            "$wsdlDir/MyWsdlFile2.wsdl",
            "$wsdlDir/MyWsdlFile3.wsdl",
            "$wsdlDir/MyWsdlFile4.wsdl"
    ]
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += "$outputDir"

dependencies {
    cxf (
            'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:3.3.6',
            'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:3.3.6',
            'org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:3.3.6'
    )
}

task generateJavaClasses {
    doLast{
        sourceWsdls.each { wsdlFile ->
            javaexec {
                classpath configurations.cxf
                main = 'org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava'
                args '-d', outputDir
                args '-b', 'PATH/TO/BINDING/FILE.xjb'
                args wsdlFile
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just simple calling javaexec of Apache CXF class - see [docs](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) for all args and options.

Note: If you have a folder with wsdl files and you want to generated classes from all wsdl files there, it is even easier and just use it like this:

```
task generateJavaClassesAllWsdlFiles {
    doLast{
        // Find all wsdl files in directory defined in ext
        fileTree(wsdlDir).matching {
            include "*.wsdl"
        }.each {
            wsdlFile ->
                println "Generating " + wsdlFile
                javaexec {
                    classpath configurations.cxf
                    main = 'org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava'
                    args '-d', outputDir
                    args '-b', 'PATH/TO/BINDING/FILE.xjb'
                    args wsdlFile
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I put it all into gist, if you want to see it complete, gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/hrabosch/4bd1bd90256fa4bb4179d2088f2a1241).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this try adding the buildScript before the plugin declarations and apply the wsdl plugin after the *plugin block* for example:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.7"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'
```

Answer (score 0):

for JDK8 you can update gradle with the following and specify cxfVersion under wsdl2java

```
apply plugin: 'no.nils.wsdl2java'

wsdl2java {
    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/fooSchemas")
    cxfVersion = '3.3.2'
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ["$projectDir/src/main/resources/emailSchemas/FooService.wsdl"]
      ]
}
```