# Generate Java Stubs from WSDL with Gradle?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, jaxb, wsdl

I'm new to Gradle but have to use it. I want to generate java stubs from a WSDL file to use in a soap call from a spring boot api to a xml web service. I've been using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMi3GlKbrHs. It seems to have exactly what I need. The problem is the project I'm working on uses Gradle and it seems almost impossible to get JAXB2 to work with Gradle. How would I convert this to Gradle? I've only worked with maven and json before, so feel free to talk to me as if I'm 4 years old, since that's true in this case.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>com.myproject.blablabla.stub</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl<schemaDirectory>
        <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.wsdl</include>
        </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: see one example in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259927/gradle-wsdl-generating